# .NET Core Angular 7 Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-universal, angular7, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to create a Angular 7 SSR using dotnet core to host it, the default template uses angular 5 and MS have documentation to get SSR running on that (which works fine) I have tried upgrading via a command line to angular 7 and start a new angular project and implement the SSR after but I always end up at the same issue, both ng build and ng build:SSR work fine from command line but when I come to run it from VS it times out (which I think has nothing to do with the issue) after it throws an error:

```
The thread 0x6608 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1134 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x54bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The changes I made from NG5 SSR (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501) 
following this (https://github.com/aspnet/Templating/issues/593) are:

startup.cs

```
options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.bundle.js";
```

to

```
options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.js";
```

Added the SSR project again to angular.json

```
 "ssr": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "bundleDependencies": "all",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Change build:ssr within package.json scripts

```
"build:ssr": "ng build --configuration=production --project=ssr",
```

Code im running - https://github.com/TPJ11/DotnetNG7SSR

Has anyone got any idea what i'm doing wrong? feel like I've been banging my head against a wall on this :(

Comment: First, 'The thread 0x6608 has exited with code 0 (0x0).' is not an error. It only means that worker thread is done, which is normal logging.

Comment: What's second? lol

Comment: Whats odd then is when it works (NG5 SSR) i never get the thread message as soon as I see that I know its going to fail. A little more detail - it starts up the .net core IIS express server fine, it starts the angular node server fine (ng serve) then it runs **ng build --configuration=production --project=ssr "--watch"** and after that it gives the thread message, however if i run that in command line it works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right so not sure what it is that breaks the app but I have the work around.

1) Create a new .Net Core NG app and delete the ClientApp folder then create a blank angular 7 app via CMD called ClientApp `ng new ClientApp`

2) Follow [angulars SSR setup guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal) up to step 3.

3) Install aspnet-prerendering  `npm i aspnet-prerendering`

4) Swap the code from step 2c (main.server.ts) to use the code in [Microsoft setup guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) for main.server.ts

5) Open `angular.json` file and change the `outputPath` for build to `dist` and server's `outputPath` to `dist-server`

6) Open `package.json` and within `scripts` add `"build:ssr": "ng run ClientApp:server"`

7) Open `tsconfig.server.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` and change `types` to include node `"types": ["node"]`

8) Open Startup.cs and as shown in [Microsoft setup guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) add

```
spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
{
    options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.js";
        options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
            ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr")
                : null;
    options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
});
```

Comment: Could you further detail steps 2 and 4 please? The documentation of those links might have changed because it doesn't seem to match your steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below step, At least it is working fine in the first run.

- Create a new .net core project using CLI or Visual Studio
- Replace complete ClientApp folder with ClientApp from this project- https://github.com/joshberry/dotnetcore-angular-ssr
- Modify Startup.cs to use SSR

  ```
  spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
          {
              options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.js";
                  options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
                      ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr")
                          : null;
              options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
          });
  ```