# .net core and angular enable ssr

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering

I have an angular and .net core default template app(the template which is provided in visual studio).
I need to enable **SSR**.
Here is the only option for SSR that is available for ssr.

In csproj File

```
<!-- Set this to true if you enable server-side prerendering -->
<BuildServerSideRenderer>true</BuildServerSideRenderer>
```

How can I enable SSR in **aspnet-prerendering** or **node**?

Comment: Maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356741/net-core-angular-7-server-side-rendering

Comment: @R.Richards Just check it, UseSpaPrerendering is out of the box, The answer is old.

Comment: This article works at this time: https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-6df7adacbdaa

Comment: @ShervinIvari any success? if yes, please share the code